# fatal Error: unable to create temporary file in imagick?

Tags: php, imagick

I have some pdfs in a folder called downloads and i want to generate thumbnails in jpg format using imagick in php but i am getting error as unable to create temporary file.
error i am getting is this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to create temporary file `/home/vrwebqbj/public_html/virtuereal.com/KyoritsuElectric/admin/images/downloads/demoPDF.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/397' in /home/vrwebqbj/public_html/virtuereal.com/KyoritsuElectric/admin/imagickTest2.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /home/vrwebqbj/public_html/virtuereal.com/KyoritsuElectric/admin/imagickTest2.php(14): Imagick->__construct('/home/vrwebqbj/...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/vrwebqbj/public_html/virtuereal.com/KyoritsuElectric/admin/imagickTest2.php on line 14
```

This is so far I tried :

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
$source       = __DIR__."/images/downloads/demoPDF.pdf"; //Source PDF File
$target     = "myfile.jpg"; // Output File



/*function genPdfThumbnail($source, $target)
    {*/
        //$source = realpath($source);
        $target = dirname($source).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$target;
        //echo $target;
        //echo __DIR__;
        $im     = new Imagick($source."[0]"); // 0-first page, 1-second page
        $im->setImageColorspace(255); // prevent image colors from inverting
        $im->setimageformat("jpeg");
        $im->thumbnailimage(160, 120); // width and height
        $im->writeimage($target);
        $im->clear();
        $im->destroy();
   // }
    //genPdfThumbnail('images/downloads/demoPDF.pdf','myfile.jpg');
?>
<img src="KyoritsuElectric/admin/images/downloads/myfile.jpg" />
```

Comment: change your `$target = "myfile.jpg";` to `$targe = __DIR__ . "/some_writeable_folder/myfile.jpg";`

Comment: No,That is not working. Actually I am very new for imagick so dont know how does it work. Can you see the error and tell what is wrong ?

Comment: From error i see it tells that library can't create temporary file, that is why i suggested you to change `$target` to some other writable directory, to what you have changed it ? have you checked if that folder has write permission ? you should not change it to exactly `$target = __DIR__ . "/some_writeable_folder/myfile.jpg";` but instead `some_writeable_folder` should be path to your writable directory

Comment: Same problem I changed it to $target     = __DIR__."/images/downloads2/myfile.jpg"; // Output File and set file permission as 0777

Comment: `Imagick` is trying to create in your mentioned `$target` folder some temporary file for its proposes you have to make `downloads2` fully  public folder

Comment: I changed my code as:
$source = "images/downloads/demoPDF.pdf"; //Source PDF File
$target = "images/downloads2/myfile.jpg"; // Output File

both downloads and downloads2 folders exist when seen through filezilla

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101034/discussion-between-dinesh-suthar-and-armen).